# Telerik RadGridView crashes on format TimeSpan

Tags: telerik, timespan, radgridview

I'm using a RadGridView where there are two columns with TimeSpan format.

When user types a wrong formatted timespan input value, the RadGridView crashes without give me the possibility to handle the error.

I've tried to parse the value filled in the cell within the ValueChanged/ValueChanging events and CellFormatting/Cellformatted events without success.

Anyone knows how can I handle this error and avoid the app crashes?

Thanks.

EDIT-------

```
Public Sub CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Telerik.WinControls.UI.CellValidatingEventArgs) Handles Grid.CellValidating
    If e.Column.Name = "HoraInicio" Or e.Column.Name = "HoraFin" Then
        If Not TimeSpan.TryParse(e.Value, Nothing) Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This make the job.

Comment: Can you show me your code ?

Comment: There is no code to show, I fill unbound the grid. When user inserts in the TS cell a value like 03:05:22 all works fine. But when user inserts 035:22 in example by error. The Grid control crashes without posibility to handle it.

Comment: Finally I've used this event to parse the new value and if is not a TimeSpan format cancel the action: